# Escape $ from sql script running from Linux Shell

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, shell, escaping

I am trying to execute an insert statement from linux shell where one of the columns has '$2a$10$zKjqmgld1gDYB/qkDuAS' in the value. When I see the inserted data the value is truncated and I get only 'aKjqmgld1gDYB/qkDuAS' as any digit followed by dollar is treated by linux as a parameter passed to the script.

This is how I am executing the script

`mysql -u user --password=password -e "insert into users(id,name,password) values(1,'Some Name','\$2a\$10\$zKjqmgld1gDYB/qkDuAS')"`

I have even tried escaping the $ like \$2a\$10\$zKjqmgld1gDYB/qkDuAS, but still it yields the same truncated data , however when I do echo '\$2a\$10\$zKjqmgld1gDYB/qkDuAS', I get the entire thing back.

Sameer

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes don't nest in shell (do they anywhere else, anyway?). So, your string is effectively outside the quotes. Combine with double quotes and backslashes:

```
mysql -u user --password=password -e \
   "insert into users(id,name,password) values(1,'Some Name','\$2a$10\$zKjqmgld1gDYB/qkDuAS')"
```

Answer (score 0):

it was already in double quotes (sorry, for writing the wrong query). That didn't work either, however I found a workaround
 
`echo "insert into users(id,name,password) values(1,'Some Name','\$2a\$10\$zKjqmgld1gDYB/qkDuAS')" >> temp.sql
mysql -u user --password=password < temp.sql`

This finally worked.